# Image View disappearing on device orientation change - iPhone - objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, user-interface, device-orientation

I'm messing around learning about changing UI layout when the orientation of the device changes on the iPhone and I've run into a problem..

I have a master-detail application, if I change the orientation when I'm in the detail view everything works fine, but if I change it in the master view controller and then push the detail view, everything works except my image view doesn't show up..

Here is the associated code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)){
        [self layoutLandscape];
    }
    else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)){
        [self layoutPortrait];
    }

    //set up UI elements
    nameLabel.text = name;
    dateOfBirthLabel.text = dateOfBirth;
    numberOfVotesLabel.text = numberOfVotes;
    reasonForFameLabel.text = reasonForFame;
    numberOfStarsLabel.text = numberOfStars;
    [indicator startAnimating];
    //Perform this method in background (gets the product image from URL)
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadImage) withObject:nil];

    //Gives UIImageView memeThumb a orange border
    //Must import the QuartsCore Framework for this to work
    [imageView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    [imageView.layer setBorderWidth: 2.0];
}

- (void) layoutLandscape{
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 150);
    indicator.frame = CGRectMake(150, 40, 20, 20);

    nameMarker.frame = CGRectMake(70, 115, 51, 150);
    dateOfBirthMarker.frame = CGRectMake(20, 135, 101, 180);
    numberOfVotesMarker.frame = CGRectMake(233, 10, 134, 30);
    reasonForFameMarker.frame = CGRectMake(230, 60, 137, 30);
    numberOfStarsMarker.frame = CGRectMake(236, 110, 130, 30);

    nameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(125, 175, 135, 30);
    dateOfBirthLabel.frame = CGRectMake(125, 210, 135, 30);
    numberOfVotesLabel.frame = CGRectMake(372, 10, 134, 30);
    reasonForFameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(372, 60, 135, 30);
    numberOfStarsLabel.frame = CGRectMake(372, 110, 135, 30);
}

- (void) layoutPortrait{
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 197);
    indicator.frame = CGRectMake(150, 109, 20, 20);

    nameMarker.frame = CGRectMake(106, 225, 51, 30);
    dateOfBirthMarker.frame = CGRectMake(56, 263, 101, 30);
    numberOfVotesMarker.frame = CGRectMake(23, 301, 134, 30);
    reasonForFameMarker.frame = CGRectMake(20, 339, 137, 30);
    numberOfStarsMarker.frame = CGRectMake(27, 377, 130, 30);

    nameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(165, 225, 135, 30);
    dateOfBirthLabel.frame = CGRectMake(165, 263, 135, 30);
    numberOfVotesLabel.frame = CGRectMake(165, 301, 134, 30);
    reasonForFameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(165, 339, 135, 30);
    numberOfStarsLabel.frame = CGRectMake(165, 377, 135, 30);
}

- (void) loadImage {
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    imageView.image = image;
    [indicator stopAnimating];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {
        [self layoutLandscape];
    }
    else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) {
        [self layoutPortrait];
    }
}
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

viewDidLoad will not be called if the view is already created and resident in memory.

try moving your code to

```
-(void) viewWillAppear
{
   UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)){
        [self layoutLandscape];
    }
    else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)){
        [self layoutPortrait];
    }
}
```